# I have a caching Servlet Filter, How do I make sure it doesn't send caching headers if there are cookies set on the response?

Tags: java, caching, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a caching Servlet Filter, the filter will, for certain URLs, add a `Cache-Control: public, max-age=x` header to responses.

But it shouldn't publicly cache any responses that are setting any cookies.  How do I check to make sure the response doesn't have cookies set (including making sure the servlet container isn't going to send a JSESSIONID)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `HttpServletResponseWrapper`:

```
public void doFilter(..) {
   chain.doFilter(request, new Wrapper(response));
}
```

where the `Wrapper` extends `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, overrides the `addCookie` method, call `super.addCookie(..)` and sets a boolean to `true`, meaning a cookie has been added. That boolean can be either in a field of the wrapper or as request attribute. Either way you can read it later when you need to check if a cookie has been added.

For `jsessionid` (appended to the URL) you can override the [`encodeRedirectURL`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29), and check whether the call to `super.encodeRedirectURL(..)` will append the jsessionid

But not caching a resource that is sending a session cookie might be wrong. Any resource might send a session cookie, if it is the first one to open.

Comment: Good idea. Would this work for the JSESSIONID which is set by the servlet container?

Comment: I just tried it out, it correctly detects any cookies that my code adds, but it doesn't call the overidden `encodeRedirectURL` or `addCookie` when it sends the JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: oh, I meant the ;jsessionid that is added to the URL. For the jsessionid cookie - I can't think of a way now. But check my update.